# PHP file not showing up from localhost

Tags: php, html, apache

I'm new to php and i'm trying to render a php script from `localhost`. I have apache2 installed and running. I have also installed php5.
I have two files in `/var/www/html/`, one is a simple html file without any php. When I try to browse the `index.html` it renders fine.

I have one more file called `index.php` which is as shown:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>My first PHP page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <?php echo date( "r"); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

And the page displays blank on browsing this file from localhost `http://localhost/index.php`.

Can any one point out what may be wrong ??

Comment: i tried running the file using php on command line and it works fine ..

Comment: Make sure you have php running by <?php phpinfo();?>.  If not, check your http.config file for mod_php module and see if it's disabled.  if you still get an error, you can check the error.log file under the same directory as your php file for further info.

Comment: You have not configured the PHP. Please follow the instructions given here: http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score -1):

Create a phpinfo.php page

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

then in browser navigate to 127.0.0.1/phpinfo.php if it show nothing then you have to setup php corectly.